# NPM basics and Local Installs?

Tags: node.js, npm, ghost-blog

I'm not regular node user, so my apologies if this is a stupid newbie question, but I haven't been able to find any clear documentation on this, and my feeble newbie node skills don't let me dig into myself.

I'm following along with [these instructions](http://docs.ghost.org/installation/mac/) for installing the Ghost blogging system, (a system built with NodeJS).

After telling me to open a terminal window in the just downloaded package folder, yhe instructions include the following line

> In the new terminal tab type `npm install --production`

This confuses me.  My understanding of `npm` is it's a package manager that, like perl's `CPAN`

1. Fetches packages from The Internet
2. Installs them into my local node system

That's clearly not what's happening above, but I don't know what **is** happening when I run that command, and since I don't run with a NodeJS crowd I don't know who to ask.

I'd like to know what NPM is doing.  Specific questions

- When I run `npm install`, it looks like it's downloading a number of packages (lots of `npm http GET` in the console). How does NPM know what to download?
- Where is it downloading these module files to?  How does `npm` know where to download the files?
- What effect does the `--production` flag have on NPM's behavior?

Happy to have specific answers, or a meta-answer that points out where I can learn how `npm` works with (what appears to be) a application installs (vs. a system install, which is how I normally think of it)

Comment: To your second point, if I've interpreted `npm`'s behavior on my system correctly, it will make a `node_modules` directory in your current directory in which it will install the modules you specified (helpful for local builds without polluting global installations on your machine). If you include the `-g` flag, then it will install the modules in a "global" location instead (which would be OS-dependent).

Answer (score 2):

`npm` has a few different installation modes. From within a module (with a `package.json` file) `npm install` installs the dependencies listed in the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` fields of the `package.json` file. Installation means that files the modules are downloaded, placed in the `node_modules` folder, then `npm installed` themselves, (but only their `dependencies`) placing modules their own `node_modules` folders. This continues until everything needed is installed. Use `npm ls` to see the tree of installed packages.

Most of the time this is what you want, because running `npm install` from within a module is what you would do when developing on it, and you'll want to run tests etc. (which is what `devDependencies` is for).

Occasionally though, you'll be coding a service that consumes modules, but should not necessarily be treated like one (not intended to be `require`'d). Ghost is such a case. In these cases, you need `npm install --production`, which only installs the `dependencies`, leaving the `devDependencies`.

Comment: I didn't want to put this in the answer to avoid muddying the waters... child modules are effectively installed with `npm install --production`.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run npm install, it looks like it's downloading a number of
>   packages (lots of npm http GET in the console). How does NPM know what
>   to download?

It reads the `package.json` configuration file in the current directory.

> Where is it downloading these module files to? How does npm know where to download the files?

It will create and populate a `node_modules` directory within the current directory. The file structure is designed in to npm/node and is (mostly) intentionally not configurable.

> What effect does the --production flag have on NPM's behavior?

Install just the `dependencies` without the `devDependencies` from `package.json`, meaning "give me what I need to run this app, but I don't intend do do development on this app so I don't need dev-only stuff".

[npmjs.org has some docs, FAQ, and man pages](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html), which are pretty good although they are mostly lacking basic introductory material.